# Eliminate files in a dir/file loop

Tags: regex, bash, loops

```
#! /bin/bash
# Script to add all scripts to the main one for dispersion to the right scripts
# Must be run in the sudo mode

if [-z $1] then                             # Set the dir to scan
    scpdir="/default-dir/";
elif
    scpdir=$1;
fi
slffil=$scpdir"thisbashfile.sh";                # Ignore this file
if [-z $2]    then                              # Set the target output file
    tgtfil=$scpdir"myoutfile";      # Ignore the target file
elif
    tgtfil=$2;
fi

for i in `ls $scpdir*.*`; do
    # Set iteration skips/continue for: '~', 'html', 'tar' $slffil, $tgtfil
    if [ "$i" == "$slffil" ]; then continue; fi
    if [ "$i" == "$tgtfil" ]; then continue; fi
    case "$i" in [*~] | [*.tar.*] | [*.html] | [*.list] | [*.deb] | [*DRBL])
        continue;;
    esac;
    echo "$i";
done
```

I need a 3rd "IF" line for the `~`, `html`, `tar` files in this directory. Should I use a regex for this or is there another simple way to eliminate these files from my dir scan?

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Also see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and note that `eq` is not a valid test operator. (`-eq` is, but that's only for numeric comparisons). And you're comparing `$1`, not `$i`. And if you want to be doing pattern matches, `case` is the right tool for the job anyhow.

Comment: `for i in "$srcdir"/*; do case $i in *~|*.tar|*.html) continue;; *) echo "$i";; esac; done` -- see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/case. And really, *do* run all your code through shellcheck; my notes are just supplemental.

Comment: Charles, Based on your comment I changed my for loop and it is not passing the shellcheck and also erroring locally

Comment: Charles,  Changed the "CASE" so it's not erroring, but not actually working as in skipping over the defined file ext or files containing the strings.

Comment: Square brackets are wrong in the `case` statement. `[aeiou]` matches *exactly one* character (a vowel, any vowel). Similarly, `[*.list]` matches the character `*`, the character `l`, the character `i`, etc.

Comment: Anyhow, there are still a whole bunch of bugs in here that shellcheck will flag. Fix those *and the issues discussed in answers to the questions linked as duplicates*, comment @-noticing me when you've done so, and I'll reopen the question if it's eligible at that time.

Comment: Note that you need to comment `@CharlesDuffy`, not just `Charles`, for me to necessarily see it; I wouldn't have noticed your prior comments if I weren't looking back over the last several days' comment threads, which is not something I typically do.

Comment: Charles, thanks for the "{}" input! Was just following a HOWTO, which showed them, but now know, not necessay!